# Capturing "quit" in the completion prompt

Tags: completion, error-handling, quitting

I need to use completion prompt, but also capture the fact when the user hits `<escape>` or `C-g`. Here's an example:

```
(let ((proj (completing-read "choose project:" projectile-known-projects)))
    (unless proj (print "never gets here")))
```

It pops up the dialog, but if you press Esc, or C-g - it just terminates the execution and never get to print anything.

I need to capture the fact of "no choice has been made" (user hits Escape or C-g). But pressing those keys while completion dialog is active would abort everything and the execution will not proceed any further.

Comment: I don't know the way, but does it help to specify the fourth `REQUIRE-MATCH` to `t`?

Comment: @whatacold no, it doesn't. Even if I put `(edebug)` as the first thing inside the block (after the let-bindings), that part still remains unreachable if Esc gets hit

Comment: The default commands for `C-g` and `ESC ESC ESC` are `keyboard-quit` and `keyboard-escape-quit`, try to bind other ad-hoc commands for them and do your stuffs there?

Comment: BTW, why do you need to capture these events?

Comment: `keyboard-quit` signals a `quit` (read about signals in the Emacs Lisp manual: do `C-h i g(elisp)Signals`). See the function `condition-case` (do `C-h f condition-case` for its doc string) for how to handle signals.

Comment: @whatacold I don't need to capture the events. I just want `completing-read` to continue through the program. Pressing Esc simply aborts everything, and it's no use to set any checks after that point, it never gets past it. I want pressing Escape and C-g to equal of selecting nothing. Instead, it just aborts it.

Comment: @NickD yes, that is what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NickD's comment above lead me to this snippet:

```lisp
(let ((selected (condition-case err
                    (completing-read "choose project:" projectile-known-projects)
                  (quit "nothing"))))
  (message "selection: %s " selected))
```

And that's exactly what I needed. Pressing Escape or C-g sets the value to "nothing"